# Repeat a HTTP request as long as the condition is not met

Tags: angular, observable, angular2-services

I am beginner at Angular and this question can be silly or repetitive , sorry for that.

My goal is to send request to a web API as long as response.Done != true and this is my code that i call a function from a service at onInit event :

```js
export class FlightListComponent implements OnInit {

  flightSearchResult: FlightSearchResult;

  constructor(private service: FlightService) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {

    let guid = Guid.newGuid();

    this.service.getAll(guid).subscribe(response => {

      if (response.Done != true) {
        this.serveData(response);
        //  this.service.getAll(guid) ....
      }

    });
  }
```

in each request i also get some data which i need to merge them to a main variable by serveData(). But i think there should be a better way to work with observable in this case that i need to call getAll() several times as long as Done is not equal to true and event give me all data at the end without merging in each request. Some how All values of each passed Observable merged into a single Observable.

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
ngOnInit() {
    let guid = Guid.newGuid();
    this.getAll(guid);      
}

getAll(guid: Guid) {
    this.service.getAll(guid).subscribe(response => {
        if (response.Done != true) {
           this.serveData(response);
           this.getAll(guid); 
        }
     });
 }
```

Don't really know the logic behind this, but you should probably debounce the nested call because you might overload the API you're calling.

Answer (score 1):

RXJS has `repeatWhen()` method. You may try to utilise it. See documentation: http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-repeatWhen
And usage example: http://blog.danlew.net/2016/01/25/rxjavas-repeatwhen-and-retrywhen-explained/

Comment: Thank you for replying. Could you please give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for retry logic, sample is below-

ngOnInit() {

```
let guid = Guid.newGuid();

this.service.getAll(guid).subscribe(response => {

  if (response.Done != true) {
    retryWaitTime = 10;
    retryCount = 2;
    counter++;
    if (counter < retryCount) {
        $timeout(function () {
              this.serveData(response);
              //  this.service.getAll(guid) ....
             ,  retryWaitTime);
    } else {
      counter  = 0;
      //return error response
    }

  }

});
```